# Does omitting the coordinating conjunction in a parallelism merit a semicolon? (not only, but also)

Tags: commas, semicolons

Which is correct?

> "Silicon Valley not only cornered the social media market; it created
>   it."

or

> "Silicon Valley not only cornered the social media market, it created
>   it."

I understand a comma is usually required in not-only-this-but-also-that sentences, but in my example, I've omitted the conjunction as I want to convey a sense of potency and impressiveness. Does this merit the use of a semicolon?

Comment: This is actually one of the most interesting questions of the day.  Does the omission of the coordinating conjunction "but" in the parallelism beget cause for a semicolon? I didn't originally think so, but it very well might. There is neither a subordinating conjunction nor a coordinating conjunction before either clause, but neither clause appears independent. They appear exactly interdependent, which is exactly what semicolons are for.  Because of the parallelism, however, most everybody at first blush would say the use of a semicolon is wrong. Is it really wrong, though? Good question!

Comment: I changed the name of your question to make it more search engine friendly.  It's an interesting question, so let's make sure it comes up for others researching the same issue.

Comment: I'd think this (the semicolon) is just wrong. Neither of the two parts makes independent sense.

Comment: This is not an instance of not-only-this-but-also-that sentences -- think out of that structure and the semicolon shows up as incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You use a semicolon to connect two interdependent clauses. In your first example, this connection is grammatically correct.

I would use a comma because the the two parts basically belong together in a *not-only-this-but-also-that* sense (as you previously put it).

Therefore, I would consider both sentences correct, but use the second one for this particular example.

> Silicon Valley not only cornered the social media market, it created it.

Comment: Much appreciated, Jera.

Comment: Would you consider "Silicon Valley not only cornered the social media market" to be an independent clause, though? "not only" is kind of a tricky one in my opinion, because you could argue that it becomes a dependent clause by way of missing information that the wording leads you to expect. I could be entirely wrong, of course.

Comment: Well, of course it becomes dependent by adding _not only_, but I would rather consider it a semantical dependency, not a grammatical one. <-- Bear in mind that concerning _not only_ this is a feeling I have. I am not sure, if I could back it up by any rules.

Comment: I suppose it is more of a semantic dependency; good answer regardless, you have earned my upvote. :)

Comment: @jera : You're right that the two clauses do not rise to the level of being independent, but I do think they achieve being "interdependent."  A semicolon is exactly appropriate between interdependent clauses.  If this weren't a parallelism that has stock grammar associated with it that prescribes the use of a comma, I'd say a semicolon is appropriate, particularly since the OP's construction deviates from the standard parallelism by omitting the coordinating conjunction "but," as in "not only, but also."  And maybe omitting the "but" does in fact make a semicolon appropriate.  Maybe.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I have nothing to say, but to agree ;)

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I think you're a bit further out on the limb than I'd trust my own weight. :-)  Is the argument that the implied "but also" mandates use of a semicolon? The argument sounds right, even if the sentence sounds wrong. Maybe a rephrase to avoid the issue is in order, such as "Silicon Valley hadn't just cornered the social media market, it created it."

Comment: @jera : Sorry, I accidentally directed those at you.  I meant to direct them to the OP.  Please forgive.

Comment: @Malcolm: I supplied my own answer, but I guess where I've arrived with this is I think you would be justified using a semicolon. I think maybe by deviating from the stock language, not saying "but," you may grammatically create a situation where a semicolon is preferred. For example: "I liked her, but I didn't love her." This uses the coordinating conjunction "but," which grammatically requires a comma before the second clause. Take out the "but," and it becomes, "I liked her; I didn't love her." If you want to imply the "but," you use a semicolon instead of a period. This may be like that.

Comment: @Malcolm : What I'm saying is you have a grammatical leg to stand on, as it were. If you want to be safe, use a comma. No one will think a comma is wrong. If you want to be daring, go ahead with the semicolon, and defy anyone to prove it's wrong. In my book, without the coordinating conjunction "but," a semicolon seems exactly what is called for. That of course counts on the rules of parallelism not applying, which you could support by the fact that you've deviated from what the parallelism actually is by not saying "but," by not creating the coordinate clause but an interdependent clause.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman no problem, I was very surprised at so much attention :D </spam>

Comment: @jera : While I didn't have a response to your agreement, it was nonetheless appreciated.  :-)

Comment: @jimm101 : Q: *"Is the argument that the implied "but also" mandates use of a semicolon?"*  A: I think maybe it does.  That wasn't my first take, but, yes, I think so.  That said, I think there would be many who would opine that the parallelism still holds even without the "but."  Of course, they couldn't prove that, but it would likely arrive at impasse with some for and some against the semicolon.  So the question becomes, be daring? Or not?  Incidentally, this is by far the most interesting question of the day so far.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of "[parallel construction](http://www.evergreen.edu/writingcenter/handouts/grammar/parallel.pdf)."

There are a number of phrasings in English that take a specific format grammatically.  This is one of those situations.

In order to write what you said grammatically, you would write:

> Silicon Valley not only cornered the social media market, it created
>   it.

While *not necessary* to rephrase it, the proforma language for this construction would be:

> Silicon Valley not only cornered the social media market, but also it
>   created it.

This particular parallelism is branded "[not only/but also](http://www.grammarly.com/handbook/sentences/parallelism/4/parallelism-with-not-only-but-also/)."

***I do get your drift regarding the semicolon.***  Written as it is, there is no subordinating (or coordinating) conjunction, so by conventional grammatical standards, a semicolon would intercede.  Were it not for the fact that this parallelism has a specified grammar already associated with it, it very well might better be written with a semicolon as it would join two clauses that would certainly be interdependent.

Now, I'm going to preach to the choir.  Being that you've deviated from the stock language that uses the coordinating conjunction "but," which is the very thing that mandates a comma be used here, it's arguable that a semicolon would be more appropriate than a comma.  So if you think a semicolon creates "impressiveness," then by all means, use one.  Just go into it knowing that some people will think it's wrong.  That would be the price of "impressiveness."

Comment: Many thanks, Benjamin. Just to clarify, I wasn't suggesting that the use of a semicolon would make me personally look impressive. Rather, I intended to emphasise the impressiveness of Silicon Valley's stature in terms of the social media market. On a tonal level the proforma example weakens this, if you see where I'm coming from.